# Crystal Report deployment for windows application

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Windows application that contains crystal reports.
I want to create a deployment project for my application.

I know how to create deployment project for crystal report but i need a way to add crystal report in the deployement.

Following are some details that might help you.

1. Development machine: windows XP 32 bit,Visual Studo 2008, .Net
   framework 3.5,Crystal report version 10.0.3555.0
2. target machine : Windows 7 with 32 bit

following are few ways how to do it but i don't know in detail how to do so.

1. adding merge module in the project..(I know these but i don't have
   merge module file and one that i have don't work correctly)
2. to use custome Action in Launch Action: but this does not allow
   Crystal report Redistribution package to be added in source file
   since it's file type is .msi (only allowed are .dll,.exe,.js..)
3. to use Installer.cs class to and override install method to start
   .msi application but i don't know how to get current installation
   path.

Guys please help me fast..I have been searching for solution for more than 3 days and now i think it's out of my current profession. :d

Thank you ,
and Best Regards.

Comment: I have tried again with merge module with the following file in Add Merge module Section.

CrystalReports10_NET_EmbeddedReporting.msm

Comment: sorry for last uncompleted commment...

I have tried again with merge module with the following file in Add Merge module Section.

CrystalReportsRedist2005_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm
policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm

CrystalReports10_maps.msm
CrystalReports10_NET_EmbeddedReporting.msm
CrystalReports10_NET_RemoteReporting.msm
CrystalReports10_NET_WebServiceReporting.msm